# Performing two actions with one button at the same time

Tags: swift

Im creating an application where I want to perform two actions at the same time with one button like it is said in the title but I don't have any idea to do that. 
Here is a part of my code:

```
//Function Test button: animate the button while playing the song
@IBAction func testButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.ButtonAudioPlayer.play()
     animView.startCanvasAnimation()
}
```

Thank you for your answers !

Comment: Can't you just call the other action from the one trigger?

Comment: What do you mean when you say trigger?

Answer (score 2):

You can call the other action from within the first action. For example, I want a button to perform its own action plus the action of another button:

```
@IBAction func buttonOneAction(sender:AnyObject){
    self.doButtonOneThing()
    self.buttonTwoAction(sender)
}

@IBAction func buttonTwoAction(sender:AnyObject){
    self.doButtonTwoThing()
}
```

When button one is pressed it will do something then it calls button two's action, preforming both. `@IBActions` are just functions like any other. `@IBAction` is strictly used by interface builder.